# The question of unix symbolic inspired from the usage of python venv executable symlink

Tags: python, unix, environment-variables, symlink, python-venv

## Question brief description

After creation of venv (either via `python -m venv .venv/` or `virtualenv .venv/`), a files tree will be created. There is a file `.venv/bin/python` or `python3`, `python3.<x>`. It is a unix symbolic link to `/usr/bin/python`. But how this symbolic link be launched with import search path for venv?

## My effort

There is little resource for this problem. But I have made some experiment:

The `sys.path` values for those two entries:

For `\usr\bin\python`

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
```

For `/path/to/venv/bin/python`

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/path/to/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
```

But when I create a directory `/path/to/empty/` and run `ln -s /usr/bin/python /path/to/empty/bin/python`. The structure of `/path/to/empty` is like below:

```bash
$ tree .
.
├── bin
│   └── python -> /usr/bin/python
└── lib
    └── python3.10
        └── site-packages
```

Those sub empty directories are all manually created.

Then when I launch `/path/to/empty/bin/python`

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
```

There is no difference against `/usr/bin/python` and `/path/to/empty/bin/python`.

According to my knowledge to unix executable, without providing arguments, the information an executable can access is environment variable, current working directory (It can be regarded as a special environment variable) and nothing else.

In the experiments above, those executable entries are launched in exact same bash console, without any preset local environment variable. And it also seems not affected by current working directory (according to `/path/to/empty/`).

## Question in general

It indicates that there is some hidden powerful feature of Unix symbolic links. Is it true?

For user aspect, what extra capability of symbolic link have which are beyond hard links.

If so, how to utilize those powerful features?

Comment: The magic is not particularly in the symlinks, but in how `venv` and then `activate` arrange things. The symlink is a nice optimization over copying the binary but hardly more than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the product of some hidden superpower in Unix symbolic links. When you run `python -m venv .venv/` or `virtualenv .venv/`, you should find that `.venv/pyvenv.cfg` has been created for you. When you then start up the python executable, it automatically imports the `site` module during initialization. This module automatically sets up your search paths. According to its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html):

> If a file named “pyvenv.cfg” exists one directory above sys.executable, sys.prefix and sys.exec_prefix are set to that directory and it is also checked for site-packages (sys.base_prefix and sys.base_exec_prefix will always be the “real” prefixes of the Python installation). If “pyvenv.cfg” (a bootstrap configuration file) contains the key “include-system-site-packages” set to anything other than “true” (case-insensitive), the system-level prefixes will not be searched for site-packages; otherwise they will.

Some testing to demonstrate:

`/usr/bin/python -c import sys; print(sys.path)` results in `['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages']` because no `pyvenv.cfg` file exists in the directory above the python executable.

`.venv/bin/python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'` results in `['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/path/to/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages']` because a `pyvenv.cfg` file was automatically created in the right spot and the `site` module found it.

`.venv/bin/python -S -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'` results in `['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages']` because using `-S` disables automatic importing of `site`, so it never looked for `pyvenv.cfg`.

If you delete the `pyvenv.cfg` file, you can see that the `site` module does not modify the search path like it did before: `.venv/bin/python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'` (without the `-S`) results in `['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages']`.

Comment: So, is `pyvenv.cfg` part of Python standard (PEP)?

Comment: @audrajacot https://peps.python.org/pep-0405/